# How do I print all the first values of an array's array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, domparser

I am using the ['PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser'](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library.
My code basically loops through my different sites and lists all the relevant anchors I need, my question is: how do I print the 1st value of the `href` in the anchor of the "selector" in each of the `$memb(n)` variables in the array of `$team`.

This is my code:

```
$memb1 = 'http://www.xyz1.org';
$memb2 = 'http://www.abc3.org';
$memb(n) = '...etc...etc'

$teams = array(
    array("url" => $memb1, "selector" => ".product-list >
                      table:nth-child(1) >
                      tbody:nth-child(1) >
                      tr:nth-child(2) >
                      td:nth-child(2) > a"),
    array("url" => $memb2, "selector" => ".product-list >
                      table:nth-child(1) >
                      tbody:nth-child(1) >
                      tr:nth-child(2) >
                      td:nth-child(2) > a"),
    array("url" => $memb(n), "selector" => ".product-list >
                      table:nth-child(1) >
                      tbody:nth-child(1) >
                      tr:nth-child(2) >
                      td:nth-child(2) > a"),...etc...etc
```

When running the foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($teams as $site) {
    $url = $site["url"];
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    foreach ($html->find($site["selector"]) as $a) {
        $links[] = $a->href;
    }
}
?>
<pre>
<?php print_r($links);?>
</pre>
```

I get all the selected anchors I wanted from all the `$memb` variables all together, yet i'm trying to print the 1st value of the href in the anchor of the "selector" in each of the `$memb(n)` variables in the array of `$team`, yet I can't find a way to do this.

I already tried `print_r(array_values($links)[0]);` yet I get only the 1st anchor from `$memb1` and it stops there, it doesn't continue to print the first anchor of `$memb2` and so on.

How can I print the 1st anchor (index 0) from every different $memb site?

Comment: What does the output of `print_r($links)` look like?

Comment: Try adding a `break;` after the line `$links[] = $a->href;`

Comment: @apokryfos, almost at the same time =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right, than try this:

```
foreach($teams as $site) {
    $url = $site["url"];
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    foreach ($html->find($site["selector"]) as $a) {
        $links[] = $a->href;
        break;
    }
}
```

or, you can do it a little bit optimized:

```
foreach($teams as $site) {
    $url = $site["url"];
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $link = $html->find($site["selector"], 0);
    if (!empty($link)) $links[] = $link->href;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a `foreach` loop if it always breaks on the first iteration. Just use `[0]` to access the first element of the array?

Comment: @clusterBuddy, please, try updated version and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array index on the result of calling `find()`

```
foreach($teams as $site) {
    $url = $site["url"];
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $anchors = $html->find($site["selector"]);
    if (!empty($anchors)) {
        $links[] = $anchors[0]->href;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would pick this answer. Using a `break` inside a loop without a condition just to get the first element doesn't seems right to me

Comment: @CarlosCarucce, agreed. updated my answer with some improvement

Comment: Your updated version is an improvement on mine, I forgot about using the second argument to `find()`.